# Discord: Get User by Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to create a web application to manage the users of my Discord server. In my database, I have stored only the users' ids.

I tried to use the discord.js API, but from what I've understood it requires a discord bot to do that. That's not what I want. I would like to retrieve the user's information from my frontend, even by calling a backend function, but without having a discord bot which is always online. In other words, I need something simpler.

I would like to request users' information by using only the id. Which is the best way to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: Discord has a Nodejs client with which you can get user information among other things. If you want to handle the logic on your client app, look into Discord REST API. Particularly here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the Discord API.

First, create a Discord application [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Once you've done that, click 'Bot' on the sidebar and create a bot for that application. There, you'll see a section called 'Token' under the bot username. Copy this and store it somewhere secure. **It is important to never share your token. If you do, you should regenerate it to prevent abuse.**

You can then use the [Get User](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user) endpoint (`/users/{user.id}/`) to retrieve the user for an ID. This should be done by the backend as it involves [authenticating with the bot token](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication).

---

### Using the API directly

Here is a minimal example of how you would fetch a user by their ID using the Discord API using Node.js:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

// You might want to store this in an environment variable or something
const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN'

const fetchUser = async id => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/users/${id}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${token}`
    }
  })
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Error status code: ${response.status}`)
  return JSON.parse(await response.json())
}
```

The response would be something like this:

```json
{
  "id": "123456789012345678",
  "username": "some username",
  "avatar": null,
  "discriminator": "1234",
  "public_flags": 0,
  "banner": null,
  "banner_color": null,
  "accent_color": null
}
```

---

### Using a library

Alternatively, you may be able to use a Discord library to do this instead. The following examples also handle rate limits.

#### [@discordjs/rest](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js-modules/tree/main/packages/rest) + [discord-api-types](https://github.com/discordjs/discord-api-types)

```js
const {REST} = require('@discordjs/rest')
const {Routes} = require('discord-api-types/v9')

const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN'

const rest = new REST().setToken(token)

const fetchUser = async id => rest.get(Routes.user(id))
```

The result would be the same JSON as described above.

For TypeScript users:

```
import type {RESTGetAPIUserResult, Snowflake} from 'discord-api-types/v9'

const fetchUser = async (id: Snowflake): Promise<RESTGetAPIUserResult> =>
  rest.get(Routes.user(id)) as Promise<RESTGetAPIUserResult>
```

#### [discord.js](https://discord.js.org)

When I first posted this answer, @discordjs/rest didn't exist yet.

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN'

const client = new Client({intents: []})
client.token = token

const fetchUser = async id => client.users.fetch(id)
```

The result of `fetchUser` would be a discord.js [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is

```js
let user = message.guild.cache.get('id');
```

(modified by @cherryblossom)

Comment: Does it require a discord bot to do it?

Comment: You added the tag "discord.js" which led me to believe you were making a discord bot, don't invalid tag. @Francesco

Comment: This code snippet is incorrect; it should be `message.guild.members.cache.get('id')` (which is synchronous will only return cached users) or `await message.guild.members.fetch('id')` (which is asynchronous and will fetch users if necessary).